# Обращение к элементам списка python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

возник такой вопрос:

У меня есть начальное и конечное значение элемента списка (в моём случае это значения таблицы). Каждое значение идёт через 0.5 от предыдущего, поэтому зная начальное и конечно, я написал свой  range, который делал бы шаг 0.5 и записывал промежуточные значения в список,по которым в будущем отбирались коэффициенты из той же таблицы и подставлялись в формулы расчёта.

Вопрос возник такой: сейчас мне необходимо записать результаты расчёта формул в файл, я могу обратиться к первому и последнему значению, которые я знаю и записать их. А как обратиться к тем, которые между ними, ведь сама длина списка может быть разной каждый раз??? (Думал через `len()`, но нормально реализовать не вышло.)

Вот простой пример моего расчёта:

Начальное значение списка a, конечное b(они достаются из файла Initial, словаря data):

```
def frange_1(start, stop, step):
    n = int((stop - start) / step) 
    range_1 = map(lambda l: start + l 
    * step, range(n)) 
    return range_1

result = [x for x in frange_1(Initial.data[a], Initial.data[b] + 0.5, 0.5)]
list = []
for j in result:
    list.append(j) 

# Затем идёт расчёт самой формулы (условно) 
H = (((4 ** 2) * 5) / list[i]) * 6
```

Значений `H` соответственно столько же, сколько и значений в списке list и в саму запись файла txt надо сделать форму:
Для `list[i]` (a = 1,2,3...b)

H = ...

Как соответственно обратиться к этим элементам??? Надеюсь выразился понятно:)

Comment: Ну берете цикл for по элементам списка, и обращаетесь.

Comment: Я понимаю как через цикл например вывести эти результаты в консоль, а вот как записать их в формат файла txt в виде: Результат: list = 1.2, H =2, ... list = n, H =n

Comment: Точно так же как в консоль, только открываете файл, и передаете его в print через параметр file: `print("Hello!", file=file)`. В цикле через print пишите в файл.

Comment: У меня там формат по строчного вывода:    file = open("test.txt", "w")    lines = ["Уровень: list[i]", "H= " + H...]    with open(r"C:\Users\...\test.txt","w") as file:    for line in lines:    file.write(line + '\n')    file.close()

Comment: Ну вот, дальше пишите цикл, и в нем выводите в этот файл.

Comment: `list` не очень хорошее имя для переменной, т.к.` list()` является встроенной функцией Питона и вы после того потеряете к ней доступ.

Comment: Я знаю, пишу же "условно"